# Is there any dependence between the shape and dynamics of the electric field produced by an electron and 'shape' of its wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-fields, electrons, wavefunction

In classical electromagnetism the electron is described by a point charge that generates an electric field with spherical symmetry when the electron is static but at the quantum level the electron is described by a wave function with a specific shape. Does the electron produces an electric field with the same shape of its wave function or there is any correlation between the function describing the electric field and the wave function?

Comment: I believe before Born came up with his postulate, $q\psi^*\psi$ was interpreted as charge density, as that’s how Schrödinger depicted it when he proposed the Schrödinger equation